# Breakpoints in TypeScript with mocha and VSCODE

Tags: debugging, typescript, mocha.js, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get `vscode` to launch mocha and stop on breakpoints. When I run the tests manually I use the following command:

```
$ mocha -r node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js --recursive
```

I can also use the following command:

```
mocha -r node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js --recursive --debug-brk
```

And the following debug config:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command.PickProcess}",
            "port": 5858,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "src/**/**.js",
                "test/**/**.test.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This allows me to set breakpoints in the `.js` files and see the original TypeScript source. But I can't set a break point directly in the TypeScript code.

My second problem is that I would like to simply press debug in the VSCode UI and trigger mocha in debug mode automatically and again hit breakpoints directly in the .ts files.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my config based on the latest task building in VSCode. Out the box it doesn't work with Typescript!? Anyway combining the answer from @Jason Dent I was able to get it working! Its also using the newer node2 debugger. For your setup, change the build/test to where ever you have put your files.

```
{
    "type": "node2",
    "request": "launch",
    // Automatically stop program after launch.
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "name": "Mocha Tests",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/mocha",
    "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/mocha.cmd"
    },
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "-u",
        "tdd",
        "--timeout",
        "999999",
        "--colors",
        "--recursive",
        "${workspaceRoot}/build/test"
    ],
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/build"],
    "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",

     // Prevents debugger from stepping into this code :)
    "skipFiles": [
        "node_modules/**/*.js",
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 4):

I had already a very similar setup as @JasonDent but that didn't work. The `node2` setting is already outdated (vscode will warn you). Instead simply add `"protocol": "inspector"` and voilá breakpoints are hit now:

```
    {
        "name": "Mocha",
        "type": "node",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "preLaunchTask": "tsc",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
        "args": [ "--no-timeouts", "--colors", "${workspaceRoot}/out/test/**/*.js" ],
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        "env": {
           "NODE_ENV": "testing"
        },
        "sourceMaps": true
    },
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Not sure why the protocol was needed but that fixed it. I've been fighting this for months!

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend a separate launch profile for debugging Mocha tests. I have the following configs, working with Mocha Typescript test.
My launch.json debug mocha profile looks like the following:

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug tests",
        "runtimeExecutable": "mocha",
        "windows": {
            "runtimeExecutable": "mocha.cmd"
        },
        "preLaunchTask": "build:tests",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--debug-brk",
            "-p",
            "tsconfig.test.json",
            "test-js/test/index.js"
        ],
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\test\\index.ts",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceRoot}\\test-js\\**\\*.js"
        ],
        "port": 5858
    },
```

*build:tests* is a vs code task, that runs **'tsc -p tsconfig.test.json'**. I had some issues in the past with gulp-typescript sourcemap generation, that's why I'm using TSC at the moment.

My tsconfig.test.json is:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./test-js",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2016",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true
},
"files": [
    "./test/index.ts"
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you figured it out by now.

Basic answer, yes you can set breakpoints in .ts files and debug them with VSCode.  They have a walk through here on general debugging: [Debugging with VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging)

The key part is that you need to make a launch profile explicitly for mocha.  This is just an example of how I got it to work.  You will need to add something like the following to your `.vscode/launch.json`.

```
{
    // Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
    "name": "Run mocha",
    // Type of configuration. Possible values: "node", "mono".
    "type": "node",
    // Request type "launch" or "attach"
    "request": "launch",
    // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
    // Automatically stop program after launch.
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    // Command line arguments passed to the program (mocha in this case).
    "args": ["--recursive", "lib/*.test.js"],
    // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
    "runtimeExecutable": null,
    "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/lib",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    // Environment variables passed to the program.
    "env": { "NODE_ENV": "test"}
}
```

This will launch mocha to test `*.test.js` files in the lib directory.

I used the following `tsconfig.json` file and have my unit tests next to the code:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "data",
    "lib"
  ]
}
```